# Linux: Sort /etc/fstab by the mountpoint field

Tags: linux, mount, sorting, fstab

On linux, how would you sort the /etc/fstab file by mountpoint?

I'm interested in sorting a section of fstab (whatever is mounted under /x) in such a way that parents are mounted before its children

```
$ grep "[[:space:]]/x" fstab
/dev/mapper/lv1         /x/a/b                  ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv2         /x/c                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv3         /x                      ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv4         /x/a                    ext4    defaults        0 0
```

The "obvious" way to do it is giving me the opposite result:

```
$ grep "[[:space:]]/x" fstab | sort fstab -k 2
/dev/mapper/lv1         /x/a/b                  ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv4         /x/a                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv2         /x/c                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv3         /x                      ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Reverting the other works in some cases, but in others it won't (not including those here, it may violate non  disclosure agreements):

```
$ grep "[[:space:]]/x" fstab | sort fstab -k 2 -r
/dev/mapper/lv3         /x                      ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv2         /x/c                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv4         /x/a                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv1         /x/a/b                  ext4    defaults        0 0
```

I've noticed it works in all other fields except the mountpoint field. Also, I've noticed that if I chop off all the fields after the mountpoint, it works as expected"

```
$ sort a -k 2
/dev/mapper/lv3         /x
/dev/mapper/lv4         /x/a
/dev/mapper/lv1         /x/a/b
/dev/mapper/lv2         /x/c
```

How can I achieve this result without chopping the fields off?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the third example?

Comment: Why do you need this sorting? **systemd** is supposedly smart enough to figure out how they depend on each other.

Comment: The third example does the job. But "sort fstab -k 2 -r" doesn't work for all the fstabs I have (50+  servers)

Comment: Cristian: Really? I tried on a virtual machine, and it couldn't mount children unless the parent listed first on /etc/fstab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-)

```
$ grep "[[:space:]]/x" fstab | sort -k2,2
/dev/mapper/lv3         /x                      ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv4         /x/a                    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv1         /x/a/b                  ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/lv2         /x/c                    ext4    defaults        0 0
$
```

-k startfield,endfield - otherwise -k2 means starting with column2 till end of line

that's it.

Peter